# Update insert and delete gridview without database

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I am able to delete and insert but I don't have idea how to select and update.  I am using `DataTable` and I don't have to to use database to update it

Markup:

```
<div>
    Name <asp:TextBox ID="TxtName" runat="server" ></asp:TextBox>
    Age <asp:TextBox ID="txtAge" runat="server" ></asp:TextBox>

    <asp:Button ID="btnInsert" Text="Insert"  runat="server" OnClick="btnInsert_Click"  />

    <asp:GridView ID="grdView" runat="server" OnRowCommand="grdView_RowCommand" OnRowDeleting="grdView_RowDeleting" OnSelectedIndexChanged="grdView_SelectedIndexChanged"   >

    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField>               
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Button ID="btn" runat="server" Text="Delete"  CommandName="delete" />
                </ItemTemplate>
                <EditItemTemplate>

                </EditItemTemplate>
                <%--<ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Button ID="btnEdit" runat="server" Text="Edit" CommandName="Edit" />
                </ItemTemplate>--%>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Button runat="server" CommandName="Change" ID="btnEdit" Text="Edit" />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
</div>
```

Code:

```
public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    public static DataTable dt;
    public static int i = 1;
    protected void btnInsert_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Session["datatable"] = dt;
        dt = new DataTable();
        DataRow dr = null;
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("RowNumber", typeof(int)));
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Column1", typeof(string)));
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Column2", typeof(string)));
        //
        if (Session["datatable"] != null) 
        {

            dt = (DataTable)Session["datatable"];
            dr = dt.NewRow();
            dr["RowNumber"] = i;
            dr["Column1"] = TxtName.Text;
            dr["Column2"] = txtAge.Text;
            dt.Rows.Add(dr);
        }
        else
        {
             dr = dt.NewRow();
            dr["RowNumber"] = i;
            dr["Column1"] = TxtName.Text;
            dr["Column2"] = txtAge.Text;
            dt.Rows.Add(dr);
        }

        grdView.DataSource = dt;
        grdView.DataBind();
        i++;
    }

    //protected void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    //{
    //    dt = (DataTable)Session["datatable"];
    //    if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
    //    {

    //        dt.Rows.RemoveAt(Convert .ToInt16 ( grdView.SelectedRow) );
    //        grdView .DataSource = dt;
    //        grdView.DataBind();

    //    }
    //}

    protected void grdView_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.CommandName == "delete")
        {
            dt = (DataTable)Session["datatable"];
            if (dt.Rows.Count >= 0)
            {

                dt.Rows.RemoveAt(Convert.ToInt16(grdView.SelectedRow));
                grdView.DataSource = dt;
                grdView.DataBind();

            }
            else if (e.CommandName == "Change")
            {
                TxtName.Text = grdView .Rows[grdView .SelectedIndex].Cells[1].Text;
            }
        }
    }

    protected void grdView_RowDeleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
    {
        grdView.DataSource = dt;
        grdView.DataBind();
    }

    protected void grdView_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: I will suggest you to use `Static` class for this purpose..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
     public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
        {
            protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {

            }
            public static DataTable dt;
            public static int i = 1;
            protected void btnInsert_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                if (Convert.ToString(ViewState["Row"]) != "")
                {
                    dt.Rows[Convert.ToInt32(ViewState["Row"])]["Column1"] = TxtName.Text;
                    dt.Rows[Convert.ToInt32(ViewState["Row"])]["Column2"] = txtAge.Text;
                    grdView.DataSource = dt;
                    grdView.DataBind();
                    ViewState["Row"] ="";

                }
                else if(Convert.ToString(ViewState["Row"]) == "")
                {
                    Session["datatable"] = dt;
                    dt = new DataTable();
                    DataRow dr = null;
                    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("RowNumber", typeof(int)));
                    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Column1", typeof(string)));
                    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Column2", typeof(string)));
                    //
                    if (Session["datatable"] != null)
                    {

                        dt = (DataTable)Session["datatable"];
                        dr = dt.NewRow();
                        dr["RowNumber"] = i;
                        dr["Column1"] = TxtName.Text;
                        dr["Column2"] = txtAge.Text;
                        dt.Rows.Add(dr);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        dr = dt.NewRow();
                        dr["RowNumber"] = i;
                        dr["Column1"] = TxtName.Text;
                        dr["Column2"] = txtAge.Text;
                        dt.Rows.Add(dr);
                    }

                    grdView.DataSource = dt;
                    grdView.DataBind();
                    i++;
                }
            }

            //protected void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            //{
            //    dt = (DataTable)Session["datatable"];
            //    if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
            //    {

            //        dt.Rows.RemoveAt(Convert .ToInt16 ( grdView.SelectedRow) );
            //        grdView .DataSource = dt;
            //        grdView.DataBind();

            //    }
            //}

            protected void grdView_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
            {
                if (e.CommandName == "delete")
                {
                    dt = (DataTable)Session["datatable"];
                    if (dt.Rows.Count >= 0)
                    {

                        dt.Rows.RemoveAt(Convert.ToInt16(e.CommandArgument ));
                        grdView.DataSource = dt;
                        grdView.DataBind();

                    }

                }
                else if (e.CommandName == "Change")
                {
                    dt = (DataTable)Session["datatable"];
                  //  TxtName.Text = (string)dt.Rows[grdView.SelectedIndex]["Column1"];
                    TxtName.Text = grdView.Rows[Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument)].Cells[4].Text;
                    txtAge.Text = grdView.Rows[Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument)].Cells[5].Text;
                    ViewState["Row"] = e.CommandArgument;
                    if (dt.Rows.Count >= 0  )
                    {

                        //dt.Rows[grdView.SelectedIndex]["Column1"] = TxtName.Text;
                        //dt.Rows[grdView.SelectedIndex]["Column2"] = txtAge.Text;
                        grdView.DataSource = dt;
                        grdView.DataBind();
                    }

                }
            }

            protected void grdView_RowDeleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
            {
                grdView.DataSource = dt;
                grdView.DataBind();
            }

            protected void grdView_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                TxtName.Text = grdView.SelectedRow.Cells[2].Text;
            }

            //protected void btnUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            //{
            //    dt.Rows[Convert.ToInt32(ViewState["Row"])]["Column1"] = TxtName.Text;
            //    dt.Rows[Convert.ToInt32(ViewState["Row"])]["Column2"] = txtAge.Text;
            //    grdView.DataSource = dt;
            //    grdView.DataBind();
            //}


        }






 <div>
    Name    <asp:TextBox ID="TxtName" runat="server" ></asp:TextBox>
       Age<asp:TextBox ID="txtAge" runat="server" ></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:Button ID="btnInsert" Text="Save"  runat="server" OnClick="btnInsert_Click"  />
      <%--  <asp:Button ID="btnUpdate" Text="Update" runat="server" OnClick="btnUpdate_Click" />--%>
    <asp:GridView ID="grdView" runat="server" OnRowCommand="grdView_RowCommand" OnRowDeleting="grdView_RowDeleting" 
>
        <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField>

                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Button ID="btn" runat="server" Text="Delete"  CommandName="delete" CommandArgument='<%# Container.DataItemIndex %>' />
            </ItemTemplate>

         <%--   <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Button ID="btnEdit" runat="server" Text="Edit" CommandName="Edit" />
            </ItemTemplate>--%>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Button runat="server" CommandName="Change" ID="btnEdit" Text="Edit" CommandArgument='<%# Container.DataItemIndex %>'  />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField>

        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by this. Does this mean your problem has been solved? If you are posting a new update to your code, it should be added as an edit to your original question.

Comment: yeah it solved my problem i Posted the sol. to my prob.

Answer (score 2):

From Microsoft's [How to: Edit Rows in a `DataTable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tat996zc.aspx):

> To update existing records in untyped datasets (row index known)
>   The following example shows how to update the same data as the preceding example, replacing the collection indices with table, and column names passed as strings. You still need to know the index of the row you want to edit.

```
dataSet1.Tables["Customers"].Rows[4]["CompanyName"] = "Updated Company Name";
dataSet1.Tables["Customers"].Rows[4]["City"] = "Seattle";
```

So in your example, if `grdView.SelectedIndex` is the row index that you would like to update, setup the command as you did with your others, and then try something like the following example.

ie. to update selected row with values from text fields...

```
dt = (DataTable)Session["datatable"];
if (dt.Rows.Count >= 0 && grdView.SelectedIndex != -1)
{
    dt.Rows[grdView.SelectedIndex]["Column1"] = TxtName.Text;
    dt.Rows[grdView.SelectedIndex]["Column2"] = txtAge.Text;
    grdView.DataSource = dt;
    grdView.DataBind();
 }
```

...which would use your textbox values to update the row. I left the `dt.Rows.Count >= 0` in there because you performed that check in other methods.

If you want the command button to populate your text fields with the current row's values, then you need to do the reverse of this.

ie. to populate text fields with values for selected row...

```
dt = (DataTable)Session["datatable"];
if (dt.Rows.Count >= 0 && grdView.SelectedIndex != -1)
{
    TxtName.Text = (string)dt.Rows[grdView.SelectedIndex]["Column1"];
    txtAge.Text = (string)dt.Rows[grdView.SelectedIndex]["Column2"];
 }
```

Comment: i used your code on rowcommand event like this;if (e.CommandName == "Change")
            {
                dt = (DataTable)Session["datatable"];
                if (dt.Rows.Count >= 0)
                {
                    dt.Rows[grdView.SelectedIndex]["Column1"] = TxtName.Text;
                    dt.Rows[grdView.SelectedIndex]["Column1"] = txtAge.Text;
                    grdView.DataSource = dt;
                    grdView.DataBind();
                }

            } but it gives and error because the selected index come -1 after button click

Comment: You can only use `grdView.SelectedIndex` if you have an item selected in your `grdView`. Are you trying to update it by some other value, like `RowNumber`?

If you want to check for the case that no item is selected, you can do this in your conditional like `dt.Rows.Count >= 0 && grdView.SelectedIndex != -1`

Comment: yeah i haven't selected any row because i never worked with datatable i want to select cell value on edit button click in textboxes  and  edit them

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by that. Do you want a command button that populates the text fields with the values for the selected row?

Comment: yeah i got the value of selected row by
 TxtName.Text = grdView.Rows[Convert.ToInt32 (grdView.SelectedRow)].Cells[4].Text;
                txtAge.Text = grdView.Rows[Convert.ToInt32(grdView.SelectedRow)].Cells[5].Text;
now how to Update it and on which event of gridview

Comment: @user3201772: I just edited my post. That may clarify what is happening. The first example will update your row with the values from the text fields; the second will populate the text fields.

Comment: I know @groveNl how to select but i want idea about update that selected row

Comment: @user3201772: After you populate the text fields and change them, with the row still selected, you can click a command button that will update the values. This command would use the first code sample I gave you. It selects the row from the `DataTable` using `grdView.SelectedIndex` and changes the row's values. Then you set the `DataSource` and `DataBind` to the modified `DataTable` again, just like you do when you add or delete rows.

Comment: selected index is always -1 bro

Comment: @user3201772 `grdView.SelectedIndex` shouldn't be -1 when you have a row selected, as I said. Maybe I am misunderstanding what you are trying to do. Even in your `e.CommandName == "change"` piece, you use `grdView.SelectedIndex`; you're saying it's always -1 for that as well?